# Assign note to R dataframe variables

Tags: r, attributes

Is it possible to assign notes to a variable in an **R** dataframe? This is possible in Stata and SPSS.

Comment: You can use the `comment()` function to add a note as an attribute. There's some additional info here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/adding-metadata-to-variables/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a comment as an attribute using the `comment` function.

```
x <- 1:5

# assign a comment
comment(x) <- 'this is a test comment'


# return a comment
comment(x)

[1] "this is a test comment"

str(x)

 int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 - attr(*, "comment")= chr "this is a test comment"
```

Some additional info can be found [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/adding-metadata-to-variables/)